# Getting class with Class.forName

Tags: java, reflection

Look at this line below:

```
targetClass = Class.forName(className).newInstance().getClass();
```

My question here is why does he call newInstance().getClass();

Would it be enough to write

```
targetClass = Class.forName(className);
```

?

Comment: yes, creating new instance is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sense to call  `newInstance().getClass()`, because it will yield the same `Class` instance where it was instantiated from.

Rather, it creates an extra instance, that will be "dropped" immediately. Even it will not work, if the class does not have a default constructor.

Also, the cost of the instantiation, initialisation, etc. may be remarkable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
Class<T> targetClass = Class<T>.forName(className);
```

And object creations better uses getConstructor.

```
T obj = targetClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Calling [Class.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) exhibits the problem mentioned in the javadoc.